# Is there a callable equivalent to f-string syntax?

Tags: python, string, templates

Everybody loves Python 3.6's new f-strings:

```
In [33]: foo = {'blah': 'bang'}

In [34]: bar = 'blah'

In [35]: f'{foo[bar]}'
Out[35]: 'bang'
```

However, while functionally very similar, they don't have the exact same semantics as `str.format()`:

```
In [36]: '{foo[bar]}'.format(**locals())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-b7ef5aead76c> in <module>()
----> 1 '{foo[bar]}'.format(**locals())

KeyError: 'bar'
```

In particular, [`str.format()` handles getitem syntax very differently](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#differences-between-f-string-and-str-format-expressions):

```
In [39]: '{foo[blah]}'.format(**locals())
Out[39]: 'bang'
```

Given the ability to handle full-blown python expression syntax, f-strings are wonderful and I love them. But they have one hitch: they're evaluated immediately, whereas with `str.format()` I can save the string with its formatting as a template, and format it multiple times in different contexts.

So, is there an equivalent way to save a string as a template, and evaluate it, using f-string semantics, at a later date? Other than defining a function? Is there an equivalent to `str.format()` for f-strings?

**Update:**

So, hypothetical interface here as an example:

```
In [40]: mystr = '{foo[bar]}'

In [41]: make_mine_fstring(mystr, foo=foo, bar=bar)
Out[41]: 'bang'
```

Comment: Why does it need to be something other than defining a function? That's the one obvious way to do it.

Comment: Well, say I'm reading the string from a file. How can I get f-string semantics out of it?

Comment: That's basically the same as reading arbitrary executable code from a file and executing it. Bad idea in most cases.

Comment: @kindall I suppose Guido should have considered that before he wrote the Python interpreter. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brief answer: NO.

You can read [PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) regarding these f-strings. It clearly defines their purpose, and the concept: these strings are evaluated in-place. The result is a usual `str` with formatted content. You cannot store f-strings as a template, as there is no special object for f-strings.

Your specific example is also mentioned in PEP-498's "[Differences between f-string and str.format expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#differences-between-f-string-and-str-format-expressions)" section.

So, whatever you do, you either use the inline in-place f-strings, or the old `s.format()` syntax, with different behaviour.

If you want to read an f-string from a file and evaluate it according to the syntax of f-strings, you could use eval:

```
foo = {'blah': 'bang', 'bar': 'sorry'}
bar = 'blah'

tpl = '{foo[bar]}'
print(tpl)

print(tpl.format(**locals()))  # sorry
print(eval(f'f{tpl!r}'))  # bang
```

Note how we use the f-string first, but convert the `tpl` into its own *repr* for immediate eval. Typically, for simple types, `eval(repr(val))` should return `val`. But instead of just putting `repr(tpl)` (or `{tpl!r}`), we convert the *repr* of the regular string into the f-string, and evaluate it instead.

Comment: I had a feeling that the answer would be <del>something evil</del><ins>some eval</ins>. ;) That's perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could think of, but it still uses `eval()` and it is not encapsulated well by a function (because of scoping issues) is:

```py
def ffmt_bad(text):
    return eval('f' + repr(text))
```

which works like:

```
# this does works
a = 10
ffmt_bad('{a}')
# 10


# this does NOT work
def foo():
    def bar(a, b, text='{a}, {b}'):
        return ffmt_bad(text)
    return bar(1, 2)


foo()
# NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

---

## EDIT 1

A possible workaround is:

```py
import inspect


def ffmt(text):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    _vars = vars()
    _vars.update(frame.f_back.f_vars)
    return eval('f' + repr(text))
```

which bears the [warning](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#vars):

> Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

although it works as of CPython 3.6 and CPython 3.7.

Usage is as before, except that now works independently of where it is being called:

```
a = 10
ffmt('{a}')
# 10


def foo():
    def bar(a, b, text='{a}, {b}'):
        return ffmt(text)
    return bar(1, 2)


foo()
# '1, 2'
```

---

## EDIT 2

Another possible workaround, although admittedly less convenient, is:

```py
def fize(text):
    return 'f' + repr(text)

eval(fize(...))
```

which works like this:

```
a = 10
eval(fize('{a}² = {a ** 2}'))
# '10² = 100'


def foo():
    def bar(a, b, text='{a}, {b}'):
        return eval(fize(text))
    return bar(1, 2)

# '1, 2'
```