# How to format an f-string after importing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary named `dict1` in the file `templates.py`. This dictionary contains several f-Strings, which take variables that are saved in the main file `app.py`

I do not know how to format the F-String if it is in another file.

I could technically just put the dictionary on the beginning of `app.py`, but the dictionary is very long and it would not be an elegant solution.

Comment: You don't. The variables used in f-strings need to exist at the point where the f-string is written.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46674480/1639625

Comment: Why not just use a template string and use `.format_map` on it?

Comment: Can you add what these files look like? Try to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a template as your string and then format it later. Here is an example (this string `s` might be inside your dictionary):

```
s = '{} abc {} def {}'

result = s.format(*['hello', 'world', '!'])
```

If you print the result you will get:

```
'hello abc world def !'
```

You can't easily do this with f-strings though.

Comment: This of course means the code doing the call to `format` has to know what values the string expects, which means tight coupling, which kinda makes the separation moot in the first place.